# How to use three url to make one url array. Use the same url for nokogiri

Tags: ruby

I might be crazy, but I have been trying to gather all my favorite news sites and scrap them into one ruby file. I would like to use these sites to scrape headlines and hopefully create a custom page for my site. Now so far i have been able to scrape the headlines from all three site individually. I am looking to use all three url into an array and use Nokogiri just once. Can anyone help me ?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://www.engadget.com'
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
@feeds = data.css('.post')
@feeds.each do |feed|
   puts feed.css('.headline').text.strip
 end

url2 = 'http://www.modmyi.com'
data2 = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url2))
@modmyi = data2.css('.title')

@modmyi.each do |mmi|
  puts mmi.css('span').text
end

url3 = 'http://www.cnn.com/specials/last-50-stories'
data3 = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url3))
@cnn = data3.css('.cd__content')
@cnn.each do |cn|
  puts cn.css('.cd__headline').text
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to extract the loading of the document and the extraction of the titles into its own class:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class TitleLoader < Struct.new(:url, :outher_css, :inner_css)

  def titles
    load_posts.map { |post| extract_title(post) }
  end

private

  def read_document
    Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  end

  def load_posts
    read_document.css(outher_css)
  end

  def extract_title(post)
    post.css(inner_css).text.strip
  end

end
```

And than use that class like this:

```
urls = [
  ['http://www.engadget.com', '.post', '.headline'],
  ['http://www.modmyi.com', '.title', 'span'],
  ['http://www.cnn.com/specials/last-50-stories', '.cd__content', '.cd__headline']
]

urls.map { |args| TitleLoader.new(*args).titles }.flatten
```